# Touchpad sensitivity of my Lenovo laptop decreased substantially

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo

The touchpad sensitivity of my Lenovo laptop decreased substantially after switching from Windows to Ubuntu.

I tried to install synaptics driver, but that did not improve it.

Earlier my touchpad was very sensitive (what I like) but now I have to swipe a lot. Any help ?

Comment: @ Prateek Jhunjhunwala : What is the Ububtu version you hace ? I have the same problem but the other way arourd. My mouse is crolling too fast. I'll ley you know if I find someting about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak the sensitivity from `xinput`.

First thing is get to know the touchpad id with:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
........
```

So my touchpad is **ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad** with id 13.

Now check the acceleration profile with it:

```
$ xinput list-props 13 | grep Accel
Device Accel Profile (262): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):    12.500000
```

The value for **Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263)** is the one that you will need to change.

You can decrease this value to reduce the deceleration (make it faster) by:

```
$ xinput set-prop 13 263 1.25
```

The number 13 here is the ID of your touchpad, 263 here is the option that you want to change, 1.25 will make it twice faster, you can try it out to see what value fits your expectation.

Reference: [How can I set mouse sensitivity, not just mouse acceleration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90572/how-can-i-set-mouse-sensitivity-not-just-mouse-acceleration)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it long time back itself. Posting the solution today -

You can modify the touchpad speed using the following commands (in your terminal):

"synclient AccelFactor=0.5"

"synclient MinSpeed=3"

"synclient MaxSpeed=7"

Higher values mean higher sensitivity. AccelFactor is the acceleration, how fast does the cursor move if you try to move your pointer. MinSpeed and MaxSpeed put a lower and upper limit to the speeds with which it can move.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this;

```
xset m 2 1
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

from top of my head, so don't pin it on me, the first [xset], made the mouse twice as fast. The second [synclient] disabled the touchpad which can become an annoyance, if one uses the trackpoint regularly.

Comment: What's the point of this answer when the OP already posted a solution? Again, do not post comments as answers.